# How do you give a user permission with CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, admin, roles, cancan

I'm using CanCan for user permission. I set it up well and have:

```
def initialize(user)
# Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.role? :admin
        can :manage, :all

    else        
        can :create, Post           
        can :read, Post
    end

    def role?(role)
        return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
    end
```

My question is how do I actually give a user a role, meaning right now all the users fall into the else category... how do i make a user associate with :admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to add a string `role` attribute to your user.

Then, in your user model:

```
def role?(arg)
  self.role.to_sym == arg.to_sym
end
```

And delete the `role?` method in the Ability model, you don't need it for your example.

Comment: CanCan and roles are completely independent : all CanCan does is say whether a user is authorized to perform a given action. Whether you want to use roles to determine this or simple flags (e.g. user.admin?) is completely up to you. All CanCan cares about is that your method return a boolean equivalent answering the question "can the current user do this ?".